# mongodb multi-state index query and schema design

Tags: mongodb

I have 5TB of data in the mongodb shared cluster, read and write ratio is 5: 5. The collection object include property attributes of many states, for example:

```
Status: {
     IsVaild: true,
     IsCancel: false,
     IsAnalysis: true
   ... more
}
```

We can not create an index for each property. If you use bitwise operations (merge all states into one value), you can not use indexes when using an operator like the $ bitsAnySet;

The other way is to put all the state into an array, and then create an index for the array, but for mongodb, the resulting multi index.

For this multi-state combination of query and index processing, we have any better solution?

> PS: mongodb does not support index for bitwise query https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24749;

Comment: How many states exactly? You may not be able to use a bitwise operator explicitly and use an index, however a bit of smart design should make it possible in most cases to effectively create integer values where you should be able to search for a mask with a combination. It really depends on the actual requirement and would therefore help if you could be a lot more specific in the question.

Comment: thanks. total 6-10 kinds of states, each query up to three kinds of state combination query, such as {isValid: true, isMaster: false, isSync: true},

Do you mean to put all the combinations into a integer values?

Comment: You are actually being asked to give a more detailed example written within the question itself. And more detailed than what you just wrote. Don't say 6-10. If there are 10 possible states then list all of them and common combinations as examples within your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn The total number of states in the collection object can not be fully determined(may be increased or decreased), but will be kept within 10 states as much as possible;
Examples of query combinations based on these states:
```
Status: {IsA: true,IsB: false,...IsF: true}

The actual case may be such a query:

{"Status.isA": true, "status.isB": false, "status.isF:" true}
or
{Status.isD ": true," status.isC ": false," status.isE: "true," created ": {$ gt; 1503025459290} / * There may be an additional condition * /}
```